# Expected return of dice game

Tags: probability, expected-value, dice

Assume our bet is always X.
To win the bet, I roll two dice and aim to make the total greater than my opponent's.

The rules apply to both players
**Rule 1.** Win twice as much if toss a double.
**Rule 2.** If tossed a double 6, win instantly without having to wait for the opponent's throw and win three times the bet.

For a normal game that does not have the rules mentioned above, the expected outcome of throwing a die is 3.5, and throwing two will give 7. Since it is a fair die, both players will have an equal expectation of the outcome and a chance of winning the game. So, the expected return will be 0.

**My questions:**

1. How would the results differ if two rules were applied? Assume that
   the sequence of throws is decided at random (50/50).
2. What would it become if I always had the first hand?

Edit:

1. If it is a tie, you get your bet back.
2. If it is a win, you get your bet back and get rewarded.
3. The bet is more like an entry fee, the cost of the ticket for playing this game.
4. The gain you make is not directly from your opponent's bet.
5. The bet is the base for multiplication decided by the outcome of your throw.
6. Win with greater sum has 1x of bet rewarded; With a double tossed, 2x; With a double 6, 3x. Only picking the highest.
7. Your gain is the bet times the multiplication mentioned above.
8. Whenever a player hit a (6,6), the game ends immediately and that player wins, his opponent will not even have the chance to throw the dice.

Comment: The rules are unclear.  How are ties handled?  I suppose $(6,6)$ is different from a general tie, but it isn't clear.  If my opponent beats me with $(4,4)$, say, do I *lose* $2X$?

Comment: I added some notes. Hope it helps make the situation clearer.

Comment: So, just go case by case.  It's slightly painful because you have to isolate doubles, but there are only $6$ possible doubles. I'd suggest handling the cases where you win or lose by a double first, then look at cases where neither player gets a double (so the probability of winning is $\frac 12\times (1-p_{tie})$.